# Magic Square FreePascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal, magic-square

Program must output whether the square is magic square or not.

I must read square from file.

Magic square - all rows, all columns and both diagonals sum must be equal.

Program shows right answer, but these 16 numbers must be read from text file.

Text file is looking like:

```
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
```

Program itself:

```
var
  m:array[1..4,1..4] of integer;
  i:byte;
  j:byte;
  r1,r2,r3,r4,c1,c2,c3,c4,d1,d2:integer;

begin

for i:=1 to 4 do
  for j:=1 to 4 do

  begin
    write('Enter value for column=',i,' row=',j,'  :');
    readln(m[i,j]);
  end;

r1:=m[1,1]+m[1,2]+m[1,3]+m[1,4];
r2:=m[2,1]+m[2,2]+m[2,3]+m[2,4];
r3:=m[3,1]+m[3,2]+m[3,3]+m[3,4];
r4:=m[4,1]+m[4,2]+m[4,3]+m[4,4];
c1:=m[1,1]+m[2,1]+m[3,1]+m[4,1];
c2:=m[1,2]+m[2,2]+m[3,2]+m[4,2];
c3:=m[1,3]+m[2,3]+m[3,3]+m[4,3];
c4:=m[1,4]+m[2,4]+m[3,4]+m[4,4];
d1:=m[1,1]+m[2,2]+m[3,3]+m[4,4];
d2:=m[1,4]+m[2,3]+m[3,2]+m[4,1];

if (r1=r2) and (r2=r3) and (r3=r4) and (r4=c1) and (c1=c2) and (c2=c3) and (c3=c4) and (c4=d1) and (d1=d2) then
  begin
  write('Magic Square');
  end

else
  begin
  write('Not Magic Square');
  end;

readln;

end.
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, you could try replacing `readln` in the loop with `read` and then running your program from the command line like this: `yourprogram < inputfile` (you might also need to get rid of the final `readln;`. However, if this is a homework then perhaps you are expected to open the file in your code using a dedicated data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a procedure to read the matrix from a text file.
The row elements are supposed to be separated with space.

```
type
  TMatrix = array[1..4,1..4] of integer;

procedure ReadMatrix( const filename: String; var M: TMatrix);
var
  i,j : integer;
  aFile,aLine : TStringList;
begin
  aFile := TStringList.Create;
  aLine := TStringList.Create;
  aLine.Delimiter := ' ';
  try
    aFile.LoadFromFile(filename);
    Assert(aFile.Count = 4,'Not 4 rows in TMatrix');
    for i := 0 to 3 do
    begin
      aLine.DelimitedText := aFile[i];
      Assert(aLine.Count = 4,'Not 4 columns in TMatrix');
      for j := 0 to 3 do
        M[i+1,j+1] := StrToInt(aLine[j]);
    end;
  finally
    aLine.Free;
    aFile.Free; 
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, because my computer got broken. I will reply as soon as I have tried it.

Comment: `Error: Identifier not found "TStringList"` and `Error: Identifier not found "try"`

Comment: `TStringList`is declared in `classesh.inc`.

Comment: Insert this line after your uses declaration, `{$i classesh.inc}`.

Comment: `Can't open include file "classesh.inc"`

Comment: OK, try `uses Classes,SysUtils;` then. See [TString_List-TString_Tutorial](http://wiki.freepascal.org/TString_List-TString_Tutorial).